# How to use MediaCodec class to decode H.264 streams

Tags: android, video, h.264, decoder

I have been asked to display a video stream (the stream is not from HTTP)in android, the stream is raw H.264 which is Recorded and encoded in a PC ,and I get it through WIFI.

When I get the stream, can use the MediaCodec decoder to decode the stream and display it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Configure the MediaCodec as a "video/avc" decoder, and pass an output Surface to the configure() call.

The MediaCodec API is pretty low-level, and there's not a lot of sample code available.  It might be easier to use `MediaPlayer` instead.

**Update:**
There's now a bunch of sample code [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).  Most of it makes use of Android 4.3 (API 18) features, but if you don't need `MediaMuxer` or Surface input to `MediaCodec` it'll work on API 16.

Comment: But,I cannot find a way to deal with H.264 stream with MediaPlayer .any ideals?

Comment: Let me back up a step.  What exactly is the format -- elementary stream, PES, ...?  MediaCodec accepts elementary stream data, but it doesn't accept it was a *stream*; it takes a series of "access units", so if it's an elementary stream you need to preserve or recover the "packet" boundaries.  You also need to ensure that the first buffer passed in has the codec info it wants, which isn't currently documented.  Your best bet may be to convert the stream on the PC side to something MediaPlayer can handle.

Answer (score 0):

See the Video Encoding Recommendations [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations)